# У меня есть проблема почему после функции pervod, переменная A1 становиться равной 0 а другие нет?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int mas[3][16];
int A1 = 0;
int B1 = 0;
int C1 = 0;
int j = 0;
void pervod(int value)
{
    int z = 0;
    if (value < 0)
    {
        z = value;
        value *= -1;
    }
    for (int i = 16; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((1 << i) & value)
        {
            mas[j][i] = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            mas[j][i] = 0;

        }
    }
    if (z < 0)
    {
        mas[j][16] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 16; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << mas[j][i] << "  ";
    }
    j++;
    cout << endl;   
}
int sum1[16];

void sum(int q[3][16], int q1[3][16], int A, int B, int C1, int C2)
{
    int kol = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if (q[A][i] == 1 && q1[B][i] == 1 && kol == 0)
        {
            sum1[i] = 0;
            kol++;
        }
        if (q[A][i] == 1 && q1[B][i] == 0)
        {
            sum1[i] = 1;
        }
        if (q[A][i] == 0 && q1[B][i] == 1)
        {
            sum1[i] = 1;
        }
        if (q[A][i] == 0 && q1[B][i] == 0 && kol == 0)
        {
            sum1[i] = 0;
        }
        if (q[A][i] == 1 && q1[B][i] == 1 && kol > 0)
        {
            sum1[i] = 0;
            kol++;
        }
        if (q[A][i] == 0 && q1[B][i] == 0 && kol > 0)
        {
            sum1[i] = 1;
            kol--;
        }
    }
    if (C1 < 0 && C2 < 0)
    {
        sum1[16] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sum1[16] = 0;


    }
    for (int i = 16; i>= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << sum1[i] << "  ";
    }
}
void sub(int z[3][16], int z1[3][16], int A, int B)
{

}
int main()
{
    int p = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите число: "<<endl;
    cin >> A1;
    p = A1;
    cin >> B1;
    cin >> C1;
    pervod(A1);
    pervod(B1);
    pervod(C1);
cout<<A1<<endl;//Почему выводит ноль 
    sum(mas,mas, 0, 2, A1, B1);

}
```

Comment: Потому что вы вылетаете за пределы массива `mas` - вот этот вылет за границу может попадать в `A`. Undefined behaviour, что вы хотите...

Comment: ты 2 раза подключил conio.h? зачем?